# Table data entry for multiple records in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, multiple-records

I am building an application and one of the requirements for my application is that when the user has to create the Volume per transaction they user wants to be able to put several transactions before clicking save, so the user have an option to add an row to the Table (using javascript).  The following is an image of what I am talking about.

[image]

I have a class for my View called VolumeConfigModel and ConfigItem which the code is the following:

```
public class VolumenConfigViewModel
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public List<ConfigItem> Configurations { get; set; }

}

public class ConfigItem
{
    public int TranTypeId { get; set; }
    public int MaxVolume { get; set; }
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
}
```

My Add.cshtml file looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<VolumenConfigViewModel>
<form id="addVolConfig" asp-controller="Volumen" asp-action="Add" role="form" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.CompanyId" />
<div><span>Configurations for Company @Model.CompanyName</span></div>
<table class="table" id="tblConfig" name="tblConfig">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tran Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Payment Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Max Vol
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var grd in Model.Configurations)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => grd.TranTypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TranTypes, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => grd.PaymentId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Payments, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => grd.MaxVolume)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here are my two questions:**

1. How can I add the new row each time the user click Add Row?
2. How do I send the information back to the Controller as List?

Sorry that I am asking two questions, but both are linked to the same problem.

Thank you very much for your help on this.

Comment: You can clone existing row to add new and to send list you need to name your controls as Configurations[0].TranTypeId

Comment: thanks for your comment; can you give some code how to do that (the part to send to the controller, the clone part I know how to do it). I tried that and my controller doesn't see the values.

Comment: check the answer

Comment: remember after cloning you need change the element name and id to new index like [lastindex+1]

Comment: Would you be interested in using a plugin for your table like dataTable? (Add row example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html, // Table with Input Controls Example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html)

Answer (score 2):

MVC binder will use name to bind data back to model so if you put name like Configurations[0].TranType it will send back as list. You can use below extension method to achieve that

This one is for dropdown

```
/// Custom helper to return select element for each property in the object that is represented by the expression and element is made disabled depending on the give input
    /// This SubDropDownListFor is used to generate DDropdown IDs fully compatible with ModelBinder when submitting a list of items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <param name="selectList"></param>
    /// <param name="elementIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="optionLabel"></param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <param name="isReadOnly"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString SubDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, SelectList selectList,int elementIndex, string optionLabel = null, object htmlAttributes = null, bool isReadOnly = false)
    {
        var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        if (isReadOnly)
        {
            attrs.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        Func<TModel, TProperty> method = expression.Compile();
        TProperty prop = method(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        var dropdownName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        dropdownName = dropdownName.Substring(dropdownName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^.*?\(.*\)\.Model\.(?<par1>.*?)\.ElementAt.*\)\.(?<par2>.*?)$");
        MatchCollection mcKVPs = r.Matches(expression.Body.Reduce().ToString());
        var kvps = from Match m in mcKVPs
                   where mcKVPs != null
                   where mcKVPs.Count > 0
                   select new
                   {
                       val1 = m.Groups["par1"].Value,
                       val2 = m.Groups["par2"].Value
                   };
        var kvp = kvps.FirstOrDefault();
        var selectTag = new TagBuilder("select");
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var displayname = metaData.DisplayName.IsNull() ? dropdownName : metaData.DisplayName;
        if (kvp.IsNotNull())
        {
            selectTag.Attributes["id"] = kvp.val1 + "_" + elementIndex + "_" + kvp.val2;
            selectTag.Attributes["name"] = kvp.val1 + "[" + elementIndex + "]." + kvp.val2;
        }
        else
        {
            selectTag.Attributes["id"] = attrs["id"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["id"].ToString() : elementIndex+"_"+dropdownName;
            selectTag.Attributes["name"] = attrs["name"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["name"].ToString() : "[" + elementIndex + "]." + dropdownName;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder().AppendLine();
        if (optionLabel != null)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(new SelectListItem { Text = optionLabel, Value = "" }));
        }
        if (selectList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in selectList)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(item, prop.ToCString()));
            }
        }
        selectTag.InnerHtml = builder.ToString();
        selectTag.MergeAttributes(attrs);
        return new MvcHtmlString(selectTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

    }
    private static string ListItemToOption(SelectListItem item,string selected=null)
    {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("option")
        {
            InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text)
        };
        if (item.Value != null)
        {
            builder.Attributes["value"] = item.Value;
        }
        if (item.Value == selected)
        {
            builder.Attributes["selected"] = "selected";
        }
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
```

This is for textbox

```
 /// <summary>
    ///  Custom helper to return text element for each property in the object thet is represented by the expression and element is made read only depending on the give input
    ///  This SubtextboxFor is used to generate TextBox IDs fully compatible with ModelBinder when submitting a list of items.
    ///  Note:it applys a readonly class to the element make sure you have a class named "readOnly"
    /// Also if you want to format you can use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType and DisplayFormat to define the datatype and its format.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <param name="elementIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <param name="isReadOnly"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>
    /// <![CDATA[ consider Model is IEnumerable<Client> @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++) { @Html.SubTextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Products.ElementAt.ProductDetailsID,i) } output textbox name is Client.Products[i].ProductDetailsID which allows modelbinder to bind it properly  ]]>
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public static MvcHtmlString SubTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, int elementIndex, object htmlAttributes = null, bool? isReadOnly = null)
    {
        var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        if (isReadOnly ?? false)
        {
            if (attrs.ContainsKey("class"))
                attrs["class"] = attrs["class"] + " readOnly";
            else
                attrs.Add("class", "readOnly");
            attrs.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        }
        Func<TModel, TProperty> method = expression.Compile();
        TProperty val = method(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        var textboxName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        textboxName = textboxName.Substring(textboxName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^.*?\(.*\)\.Model\.(?<par1>.*?)\.ElementAt.*\)\.(?<par2>.*?)$");
        MatchCollection mcKVPs = r.Matches(expression.Body.Reduce().ToString());
        var kvps = from Match m in mcKVPs
                   where mcKVPs != null
                   where mcKVPs.Count > 0
                   select new
                   {
                       val1 = m.Groups["par1"].Value,
                       val2 = m.Groups["par2"].Value
                   };
        var kvp = kvps.FirstOrDefault();
        var inputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var displayname = metaData.DisplayName.IsNull() ? textboxName : metaData.DisplayName;
        if (kvp.IsNotNull())
        {
            inputTag.Attributes["id"] = kvp.val1 +"_"+ elementIndex +"_"+ kvp.val2;
            inputTag.Attributes["name"] = kvp.val1 + "[" + elementIndex + "]." + kvp.val2;
        }
        else
        {
            inputTag.Attributes["id"] = attrs["id"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["id"].ToString() : elementIndex + "_" + textboxName;
            inputTag.Attributes["name"] = attrs["name"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["name"].ToString() : "[" + elementIndex.ToString() + "]." + textboxName;
        }
        inputTag.Attributes["type"] = "text";
        switch (metaData.DataTypeName)
        {
            case "Currency":
                inputTag.Attributes["value"] = val.IsNotNull() ? Convert.ToDouble(val).ToString(metaData.DisplayFormatString) : string.Empty;
                break;
            case "Date":
            case "DateTime":
                inputTag.Attributes["value"] = val.IsNotNull() ? val.ToDateTime().ToString(metaData.DisplayFormatString) : string.Empty;
                break;
            default:
                inputTag.Attributes["value"] = val.IsNotNull() ? val.ToString() : string.Empty;
                break;
        }
        inputTag.Attributes["value"] = val.IsNotNull() ? val.ToString() : "";
        inputTag.MergeAttributes(attrs);
        return new MvcHtmlString(inputTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

This is for hidden fields like Ids

```
/// <summary>
    /// Custom helper to return input hidden element for each property in the object that is represented by the expression and element is made disabled depending on the give input
    /// This SubHiddenFor is used to generate hiddenfield IDs fully compatible with ModelBinder when submitting a list of items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <param name="elementIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString SubHiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,int elementIndex, object htmlAttributes=null)
    {
        var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        Func<TModel, TProperty> method = expression.Compile();
        TProperty val = method(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        var hiddenfieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        hiddenfieldName = hiddenfieldName.Substring(hiddenfieldName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^.*?\(.*\)\.Model\.(?<par1>.*?)\.ElementAt.*\)\.(?<par2>.*?)$");
        MatchCollection mcKVPs = r.Matches(expression.Body.Reduce().ToString());
        var kvps = from Match m in mcKVPs
                   where mcKVPs != null
                   where mcKVPs.Count > 0
                   select new
                   {
                       val1 = m.Groups["par1"].Value,
                       val2 = m.Groups["par2"].Value
                   };
        var kvp = kvps.FirstOrDefault();
        var inputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var displayname = metaData.DisplayName.IsNull() ? hiddenfieldName : metaData.DisplayName;
        if (kvp.IsNotNull())
        {
            inputTag.Attributes["id"] = kvp.val1 +"_"+ elementIndex +"_"+ kvp.val2;
            inputTag.Attributes["name"] = kvp.val1 + "[" + elementIndex + "]." + kvp.val2;
        }
        else
        {
            inputTag.Attributes["id"] = attrs["id"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["id"].ToString() : elementIndex+"_"+hiddenfieldName;
            inputTag.Attributes["name"] = attrs["name"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["name"].ToString() : "[" + elementIndex + "]." + hiddenfieldName;
        }
        inputTag.Attributes["type"] = "hidden";
        inputTag.Attributes["value"] = val.ToCString();
        inputTag.MergeAttributes(attrs);
        return new MvcHtmlString(inputTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

This is for check boxes

```
/// <summary>
    /// Custom helper to return input type checkbox with a label element for each property in the object that is represented by the expression
    /// This SubCheckBoxWithLabel is used to generate input type checkboxes IDs fully compatible with ModelBinder when submitting a list of items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <param name="elementIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="htmlLabelAttributes"></param>
    /// <param name="htmlCheckBoxAttributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString SubCheckBoxWithLabel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, int elementIndex, object htmlLabelAttributes = null, object htmlCheckBoxAttributes = null)
    {
        var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlCheckBoxAttributes);

        Func<TModel, bool> method = expression.Compile();
        bool? val = method(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        var chkattrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlCheckBoxAttributes);
        var checkboxName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var checkboxID = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var hiddenTag = new TagBuilder("input");
        checkboxName = checkboxName.Substring(checkboxName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var displayname = metadata.DisplayName.IsNull() ? checkboxName : metadata.DisplayName;
        checkboxName = "[" + elementIndex + "]." + checkboxName;
        checkboxID = checkboxID.Replace('.', '_') + "_" + elementIndex;
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^.*?\(.*\)\.Model\.(?<par1>.*?)\.ElementAt.*\)\.(?<par2>.*?)$");
        MatchCollection mcKVPs = r.Matches(expression.Body.Reduce().ToString());
        var kvps = from Match m in mcKVPs
                   where mcKVPs != null
                   where mcKVPs.Count > 0
                   select new
                   {
                       val1 = m.Groups["par1"].Value,
                       val2 = m.Groups["par2"].Value
                   };
        var kvp = kvps.FirstOrDefault();
        var labelTag = new TagBuilder("label");
        var CheckboxTag = new TagBuilder("input");


        if (kvp.IsNotNull())
        {
            CheckboxTag.Attributes["id"] = "chk" + kvp.val1 + elementIndex + kvp.val2;
            CheckboxTag.Attributes["name"] = "chk" + kvp.val1 + "[" + elementIndex + "]." + kvp.val2;
            hiddenTag.Attributes["id"] = kvp.val1 + elementIndex + kvp.val2;
            hiddenTag.Attributes["name"] = kvp.val1 + "[" + elementIndex + "]." + kvp.val2;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckboxTag.Attributes["id"] = "chk" + (attrs["id"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["id"].ToString() : checkboxID);
            CheckboxTag.Attributes["name"] = "chk" + (attrs["name"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["name"].ToString() : checkboxName);
            hiddenTag.Attributes["id"] = attrs["id"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["id"].ToString() : checkboxID;
            hiddenTag.Attributes["name"] = attrs["name"].IsNotNull() ? attrs["name"].ToString() : checkboxName;
        }
        hiddenTag.Attributes["type"] = "hidden";
        CheckboxTag.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
        CheckboxTag.MergeAttribute("onclick", "javascript: $(this).parent().next('#" + hiddenTag.Attributes["id"] + "').val($(this).is(':checked'));");
        CheckboxTag.Attributes["value"] = val.ToString().ToLower();
        hiddenTag.Attributes["value"] = val.ToString().ToLower();
        if (val == true)
        {
            CheckboxTag.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
        }
        CheckboxTag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlCheckBoxAttributes));
        labelTag.AddCssClass("checkbox");
        labelTag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlLabelAttributes));
        labelTag.InnerHtml = MvcHtmlString.Create(CheckboxTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)) + "&nbsp;" + displayname;

        return new MvcHtmlString(labelTag.ToString() + hiddenTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

to use this you need to code your cshtml as below

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr id="dvUser-@i">
        <td>
            @Html.SubHiddenFor(modelItem=>Model.ElementAt(i).Id,i)
            @Html.SubTextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).UserName, i, new { @class="form-control" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.SubPasswordFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).NewPassword, i, new { @class="form-control" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.SubDropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).RoleId,(SelectList)ViewBag.Roles, i,"Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: is there another way beside that thi? for example using jquery?  that is too much effort just to get the data that I need. No say is wrong but is too much coding that doesn't bring too much benefits for the business. No what I am looking for. It must be there a more simpler way of doing that.

Comment: Just use html controls with the name and id created as mentioned earlier

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try some thing like this

```
@{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var grd in Model.Configurations)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => grd.TranTypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TranTypes, "Please select", new { @id = "TranTypeId_"+i, @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => grd.PaymentId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Payments, "Please select", new { @id = "PaymentId_"+i, @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => grd.MaxVolume,new { @id = "MaxVolume_"+i })
            </td>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }
}
```

To add new row see this examples https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pass-dynamically-added-html-table-records-list-to-controller/

https://patricjsson.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/asp-net-mvc-proper-model-binding-with-dynamic-form/

Answer (score 1):

If you want no refresh the page you can use ajax-form options.

```
<div id="ajaxContent">
  <form asp-antiforgery="true" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-update="#ajaxContent" data-ajax-mode="REPLACE-WITH">
    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Ajax">Add Person</button>

    <!--Form Content-->

  </form>
</div>
```

Note the data-ajax-* options and the update references to #ajaxContent. Also, the submit button with the handler **Ajax**

If you wanna limit the ajax response only to the form content you cant wrap the no ajax content into a IsAjaxRequest(). I didn't find the function IsAjaxRequest which exist in the previous ASP.NET MVC .Net Framework. So the extension method implementation is as follow:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    private const string RequestedWithHeader = "X-Requested-With";
    private const string XmlHttpRequest = "XMLHttpRequest";

    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            return request.Headers[RequestedWithHeader] == XmlHttpRequest;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use like this in your cshtml...

```
@if (!this.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
}
```

At Model side you need a list of your model, in my case, Person...

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

And the post for the ajax handler method look like this

```
public void OnPostAjax()
{
    this.Persons.Add(new Person());
}
```